# Git for Windows using Beyond Compare

Tags: windows, git, beyondcompare

I'm a newcomer to git and I've having difficulty configuring a visual diff/merge tool. I've configured git as per the instructions on http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows but when i run git difftool file.txt the diff is shown on the console, no errors are shown and beyond compare isn't launched.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Thanks

James

I'm running 1.7.6.msysgit.0 on Windows 7 x64

My config is (I've removed usernames etc)

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
diff.tool=bc3
difftool.bc3.path=c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.bc3.path=c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
gui.wmstate=zoomed
gui.geometry=584x210+275+275 408 476
```

Comment: Just to double check, you do have V3 of Beyond Compare rather than V2? (I'm on BC2...). I don't believe the instructions work for BC2. Also, do you need to quote the paths?

Comment: Yes, it's BC3. It doesn't seem to me like it's even trying to execute beyond compare as the diff is shown on the console. I'm using the mysysgit distribution http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ and I wonder if that's part of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an old(ish) thread on [msysGit forum (googlegroups)](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/7c611b1e866f56a8/2fbab593b26927bf?q=%2522David%2bAguilar%2522#2fbab593b26927bf&ei=iGwTS6eaOpW8Qpmqic0O&sa=t&ct=res&cd=45&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNFiwX0a2rrdBx5CulvKpaYc9IOe8w) . In summary, there was a change in the executable name and the fix went (should have gone;-) in a version after yours.

An update to the latest should fix it.